# Delay signed FSharp.Core assemblies

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, f#

I'm deploying a service which depends on FSharp.Core to AWS, specifically to an AMI that doesn't have the fsharp redistributable installed on it. I have thus added a reference to the fsharp.core nuget package, but the assembly is marked as delay signed - which as far as I know means I need to either:

1. Sign all my code
2. Add registry exceptions for FSharp.Core

Is there an unsigned version of this assembly, or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: You could always compile it yourself, the code is open source.

Comment: @JohnPalmer sure could, and I could even release it on nuget. I want to make sure I'm not doing something obviously stupid first though :)

Answer (score 0):

I posted this to [the fsharp github page](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/345), and it was pointed out that it's fine to reference signed assemblies from unsigned ones. I think my issue was that I had delay signed assemblies in the mix.

At any rate, it was sufficient to add the following line to the dependencies section of my nuspec file:

```
<dependency id="FSharp.Core.Microsoft.Signed" version="3.1.1.1" />
```